# Interactive commands with pipe and grep

Tags: grep, pipe, interactive

There are commands such as `top`, `watch`, `Airodump-ng`, etc, that whenever you run, everything on the terminal change all the time. What I want to do is that run one of theses interactive command and then use pipe to grep something I've been looking for. Take this for instance:

```
   airodump-ng wlan0 | grep "QQ:AF:00:55:8C:DF"
```

In this example I am looking for a MAC address, when this MAC turn up, it will appear on screen so that I can grep it.

The problem is that it doesn't work. I have searched a lot to no avail.

Comment: I still beg to differ; for example, the command `top | grep X` works just fine on my system (Debian 8). It produces output on `X` and nothing else at regular (2 seconds) intervals.

Comment: interestingly enough it works with top.very strange!maybe the problem is with airodum-ng!

Comment: Are you sure the search strings are actually present? Pipe the stream into less +F to check this point. You can even search for your terms in less command.

Answer (score -2):

see also the `--line-buffered` option of grep; it makes grep execute its test every time its stdin sees a newline

Comment: No `--line-buffered` is for `grep`'s _output_ to be line-buffered like it is when it goes to a terminal device. It doesn't affect the way `grep` reads and processes its _input_.

Comment: sorry, however it works, there's scenarios where `long-running-process | grep foo` blocks without outputting anything and `long-running-process | grep --line-buffered foo` outputs stuff as it is written

Comment: Yes, when `grep`'s stdout is not a tty and when the problem is `grep` buffering its *output*. Like in `tail -f file | grep . | cat`

Answer (score -3):

You can use the command `watch` for this.

For example:

```
sudo watch -n 1 "airodump-ng wlan0 | grep "QQ:AF:00:55:8C:DF"
```

Comment: I'll test now.I'll tell you the result